# ng-message inside md-autocomplete shows with wrong style and overlaps the input field

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages, md-autocomplete

I have an md-autocomplete with ng-messages inside of it:

```
<md-autocomplete flex required="required"
     md-input-name="player"
     md-input-minlength="0"
     md-autoselect="true"
     md-select-on-match="true"
     md-selected-item="item.player"
     md-item-text="player.name"
     md-search-text="playerSearchText"
     md-items="player in filterPlayerItems(playerSearchText)"
     md-no-cache="true"
     md-floating-label="Select Player">

     <md-item-template>
          <span>{{player.name}}</span>
     </md-item-template>
     <div ng-messages="form.player.$error" class="md-block">
         <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
     </div>
</md-autocomplete>
```

The md-autocomplete is inside a form, and everything works well, besides the fact that the error message is overlapping the input field and the label:

[image]

When checking the DOM I found that inside the `<md-autocomple-wrap>` there is a `<md-input-container>` with a `flex` class:
[image]

and if I remove that class the message goes down to its proper place:
[image]

I can see the `md-autocomplete` example on angular-material demo is working well and I am following their example.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I've stripped down the demo version and can't replicate your problem - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/kXyZgB. Could you fork it and put in your markup and code to replicate the problem?